# GIT Updating subtree: how can I update my subtree?

Tags: git, github

We have a few repo's like :

Site1:

- lib:

Site2:

- lib:

lib:

As you see lib is shared in both sites. Now when I use

```
[master] git fetch lib
```

Nothing happens.
After that I use :

```
[master] git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit lib
```

Then it starts deleting loads of files that belongs to the site.

If I try this:
Update the Library Sub-Project from the Shared Library Remote
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562950/GitplusSubtreeplusMergeplus-e2-80-93TheplusQuickpl

```
[master] git checkout lib
Checking out files: 100% (4521/4521), done.
Switched to branch 'lib'
[lib] git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Then just checkout to the master, and run the command:

```
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit lib
```

This just deletes a whole load of files from my site and leaves a few files like its in a subfolder of lib..
Why doesen't this just update the lib to the correct version? and leave the files for the site?

After a reset I do get my project back

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

How can I update the lib?

There is a remote branch setup.

```
$ git remote -v
lib     https://github.com/***/lib.git (fetch)
lib     https://github.com/***/lib.git (push)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering that you already set your subtree in your app (`git remote add subtree_name git@github.com:user/subtree_proj.git`) your have to:

1- Subtree split

`git subtree split -P lib -b new_branch_to_split` where the `lib` is the path to your subtree project and the `new_branch_to_split` will only contain your `lib` code and will be pushed to your `lib` repo.

2- Subtree push

`git push subtree_name new_branch_to_split:original_subtree_branch(i.e. master)`

or

`git push subtree_name new_branch_to_split:master`

3- Always delete the temporary branch

`git branch -D new_branch_to_split`

4- Pull the changes in your other project that's using the subtree project

`git subtree pull -P lib subtree_name original_subtree_branch(i.e. master)`

Comment: Can I do this just with local branches ? Without push or pull ?

Comment: I'd also be interested in this. I've tried read-tree, which fails for "overlapping" files...

Comment: Sorry folks I haven't been working with this git structure for some years already, don't think I'll be able to help any further, really sorry